# how to call MainViewController.h methods from html / javascript ? ( IOS Phonegap)

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am new to IOS phonegap. In my application i need to send a mail from my app. So I am using "mailto" function it is working fine but the problem is after sending a mail it is not return back to my app it is staying in mail app only. How can i solve this issue.

IF i am using below code for sending a mail instead of "mailto" how can i make a link from my html/javascript to "Mainviewcontroller.h" with button click. and how can I pass parameters from javascript/html to "Mainviewcontroller.h" class.

```
NSString *subject = @"Message subject";
NSString *body = @"Message body";
NSString *address = @"test1@akosma.com";
NSString *cc = @"test2@akosma.com";
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:%@?cc=%@&subject=%@&body=%@", address, cc, subject, body];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[path stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Please give some suggestions or guide me some good tutorials to solve my issue.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call an `Objective C` method from `JavaScript` without using a `UIWebView`.

You can do it by using a UIWebView, something like this :

In your JavaScript file:

```
...
 window.location.href = "doSomething;";
..
```

Edit :

In your `MainViewController.m`, you can add a "fake" UIWebView, something like this in `MainViewController.m's viewDidload`:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad{
        UIWebView *webView = [UIWebView alloc] init];
        webView.hidden = YES;
        webView.delegate = self;
       [sel.view addSubView:webView];

        // Know you should load the JavaScript witch contain the script.
        [webView loadHTMLString:...];
   }
```

Put the `MainViewController` conform the `UIWebViewDelegate`

and now in your `UIWebViewDelegate` ( `MainViewController.m`) object :

```
 -(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    if ([request.URL.absoluteString isEqualToString:doSomething]) {
            // Here you can call what you want
            return NO;
        }
        return YES;
    }
```

Comment: Really thanks for replay, but where can i add the below code        -(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

if ([request.URL.absoluteString isEqualToString:doSomething]) {
        // Here you can call what you want
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

Comment: Were do you put your JavaScript script ? is it in a separate file .js or is it embedded in your html file ?

Comment: I am talking about Objective C code not for java script.javascript code is included in my html and where should I place this code ==>-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

if ([request.URL.absoluteString isEqualToString:doSomething]) {
        // Here you can call what you want
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}